# When doing i-vector experiments, can I use the same data to train the UBM and T-matrix?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am now doing some speaker verification experiments using I-vectors, I just feel confused on the selection of data, especially the UBM data and T-matrix training data. Can they be the same ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, **yes**, you can use the same data, but usually *gender-dependent* UBMs are trained which means you have to train separate UBMs for male and female speakers. For more information read section 6.1 of [An i-vector Extractor Suitable for Speaker Recognition with both Microphone and Telephone Speech](http://www.sls.csail.mit.edu/sls/publications/2010/Senoussaoui_Odyssey.pdf)